# How do I force Goland to run tests every time?

Tags: go, goland

If no code changes have been made since the last time a test suite was run in Goland 2018.3, and the last test run completed successfully, Goland simply spits out the last set of results instead of actually executing the code. I need to be able to run the tests on demand as part of a demo without having to make and revert a minor code change each time to get it to cooperate. Using Testify for asserts, not sure if that's relevant to the issue I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is related to the Go 1.10+ caching support for tests. You can [read more about it here](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#test).

If you wish to disable the caching support in Go, you should run the test command with `-count=1` flag. To do the same via GoLand, go to `Run | Edit Configurations... | Go Test | <name of your test configuration> | Go tool arguments` and add `-count=1` as a parameter there, then run the configuration again.

If you want to disable this for all future generated Run Configurations, then follow the same steps as above but go to `Edit Configurations... | Default | Go Test` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's impacting the caching behavior or not, but I always land on this answer looking for how to get GoLand to run the tests multiple times and adding `count=10` to the `Go tool arguments` doesn't do it (at least when `Test Kind` is `Package`).  This is because it's actually building a test binary first with `test -c -count=10 ...` and then running the binary, which results in ignoring the count argument passed when it cwas compiled.  

Instead I have to put `-test.count 10` in the `Program arguments` box, which gets passed to that compiled test binary.